# BundleID of an iOS Application installed on iOS 10.2.1

Tags: mobile, ios

I'm fairly new to iOS Security and was trying to obtain the BundleID of the applications installed on my jailbroken iOS Device (10.2.1).

I tried using both Appster and BundleIDs but both failed to list down the applications installed on my iOS Device. I'm guessing that its probably because these applications are not compatible with my iOS Version.

> Just wanted to know of any other way to find the BundleID of applications not installed from the iOS AppStore when I don't have the IPA file available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Just navigate to
   `/var/mobile/applications` for iOS versions less than 8.
   `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application` for iOS versions less than 9.3.x and `/var/containers/Bundle/Application` for all versions greater than 9.3.x.
2. Find your application UUID (Universal Unique Identifier) and 'cd' into the folder.
3. Grep for the text `softwareVersionBundleId` in the file `iTunesMetadata.plist`.

Reference:
https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/finding-the-app-bundle-id/